# add commas in the end of the cfoutput while this cfoutput is grouped

Tags: mysql, api, coldfusion

I have a query that contains the categories with multiple products in it. I grouped it according to categories and products in the query and output as well. However, while constructing the API code, I faced the problem of commas between them. So far I have put commas everywhere, in the end as well, but I don't want to add them in the end of the category or product groups. Here is the query:

```
    SELECT P.PRODUCT_ID,P.PRODUCT_NAME,PC.PRODUCT_CAT,PC.PRODUCT_CATID,PR.PRICE,PR.MONEY,PC.HIERARCHY
    FROM PRODUCT_CAT PC 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PRODUCT P ON P.PRODUCT_CATID=PC.PRODUCT_CATID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PRICE PR ON P.PRODUCT_ID=PR.PRODUCT_ID
    WHERE P.IS_SALES=1 AND P.IS_EXTRANET=1 AND PR.PRICE IS NOT NULL

    GROUP BY PC.HIERARCHY,PC.PRODUCT_CAT,P.PRODUCT_ID,P.PRODUCT_NAME,PC.PRODUCT_CATID,PR.PRICE,PR.MONEY
    ORDER BY PC.HIERARCHY,P.PRODUCT_NAME
```

**and my output:**

```
{"status":"ok","count":<cfoutput>#row#</cfoutput>,"data":[
    <cfoutput query="get_json" group="product_catid">
        {"cat":#product_cat#,"cat_id":#product_catid#,"products":[
            <cfoutput group="product_id">
                {"id":#product_id#,"name":#product_name#,"price":#tlformat(price,2)#,"currency":#money#},<!-- i dont want this comma to be added in the end of the products group --->
            </cfoutput>
        ]},<!-- i dont want this comma to be added in the end of the categories group --->
    </cfoutput>
    ]}
```

You can have a look at [the live output of it here](http://pda.bilgiteknolojileri.net/).  As you can see, the commas are added even in the end of the grouped products, as well as in the very end, in the end of the categories group, but I don't want them there. How can I fix this?

Comment: @MattBusche how i can do it?

Comment: Leigh deleted their comment, but they're right. You should not be creating your own JSON. Create a proper struct and use `serializeJSON()` to create JSON.

Comment: @Leigh sorry im new in json, just dont undertand how i can achieve it, thus for the temporary answer this will be fine for me

Comment: @Leigh but i cant serialize the grouped complex queries, or im doing it wrong?

Comment: create a nested structure just like how you're trying to create the JSON

Comment: @venom - Do not serialize the query. Just create the CF structures/arrays you need. Then call `serializeJSON`. JSON is very easy. It is just a bunch of [structures and/or arrays formatted a particular way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840003/using-json-data-with-coldfusion/15841047#15841047).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not roll your own JSON. There are plenty of existing options that will do a more thorough job, and properly handle special characters embedded within the values (your current code does not). Just create the necessary CF structures and use [serializeJSON](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-79fa.html). Granted, the CF implementation has a few quirks, so you might also look into using one of the [JSON projects on github.com](https://github.com/search?q=ColdFusion%20JSON&ref=cmdform). Either way it is better than doing it yourself.

Anyway, in your case, the `data` element is just an array `[]` of structures `{}`.  Each structure represents a category, which among other things, contains an array of `products`.

```
    { 
       "data":[   <--- array --->
                 {"cat":xxx,  "products":[ <!--- array of products --->], ... }
                , {"cat":yyy, "products":[ <!--- array of products --->], .. }
              ]
    }
```

To create the elements, just initialize the data array before your loop:

```
<cfset dataArray = []>
```

Inside the outer loop, create a structure for each category:

```
<cfoutput query="get_json" group="product_catid">
    <!--- create new category structure --->
    <cfset category = {}>
    <cfset category["cat"]= product_cat>
    .... other keys ....
    <cfset category["products"] = []> 
    ...
```

Within your *inner* loop, create the products and add them to your category:

```
<cfoutput group="product_id">
    <!--- create new product element --->
    <cfset prod = {}>
    <cfset prod ["id"] = product_id>
    ... other keys ...

    <!--- save product to your category --->
    <cfset arrayAppend(category.products, product)>
</cfoutput>
```

Then before you close the loop, save the category to your `dataArray`

```
     <!--- save to data array --->
     <cfset arrayAppend(dataArray, category)>

  </cfoutput>
```

Finally, wrap up the status and data, and serialize it:

```
  <cfset result = {}>
  <cfset result["status"] = "ok">
  <cfset result["count"] = row>
  <cfset result["data"] = dataArray>

  <!--- debug serialized results --->
  <cfdump var="#serializeJSON( result )#">
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider a strategy that skips commas at the start of arrays.

```
{"status":"ok","count":<cfoutput>#row#</cfoutput>,"data":[
<cfoutput query="get_json" group="product_catid">
    {"cat":#product_cat#,"cat_id":#product_catid#,"products":[
       <cfif currentrow GT 1>,</cfif>
       <cfset innercomma = 0>
       <cfoutput group="product_id">
         <cfif innercomma EQ 1>,</cfif>
         <cfset innercomma = 1>
 {"id":#product_id#,"name":#product_name#,"price":#tlformat(price,2)#,"currency":#money#}
       </cfoutput>
    ]}
</cfoutput>
]}
```

Comment: no smth is wrong, the structure is not acceptable, maybe i should try work this out with `serializeJSON()` but i have to create more simple query then... btw there is no solution for cats group