# coldfusion and reading JSON data from web service into a cf query

Tags: sql, json, web-services, api, coldfusion

I am using the following code to obtain data from a webservice and it returns the data in json format

```
<cfhttp url="http://api.sensis.com.au/v1/test/search?key=czsjp3f8xhd835vg6xfw8ber&query=vetinary%20and%20clinic&radius=1&location=-37.7833,144.9667">

<cfdump var="#cfhttp.FileContent#">
```

I want to be able to output the data into a table, for that reason, I need to be able to bring the data into a query object and then I can `cfloop` or `cfoutput` the query to display each row of data for the selected data fields I choose.

However, I have not been successful in trying to achieve the above. I would appreciate, if I could be given some assistance with the code to achieve the result mentioned.

Comment: You don't need to have the data in a query object you simply need `deserializeJSON()` - https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/DeserializeJSON

Comment: i have tried the deserialising but still could not figure out how to loop over the data so i can output each of the records row by row

Comment: Have you even taken a look at the data structure? That JSON string gives you a structure where one of the keys is named `results`. This is an array, you can simply loop over that array to display the data.

Comment: hi scott thanks yes the last piece of the puzzle seems to have come to play from your first comment i am working through it now

Answer (score 3):

I believe, the answers by @[Leigh](/users/104223/leigh) and @[J.T](/users/443543/j-t) to **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840003/using-json-data-with-coldfusion)** question would help you understand the structure of JSON and how to handle it in ColdFusion.

As already commented, you don't need to convert the result to a `query` object in order to represent the data you want in a tabular format. That is the beauty and simplicity of ColdFusion, you can easily loop through an array, a collection (or struct) or a complex arrangement such as an array of structures. Learn from [here](http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/Looping/).

The JSON result of the http call in your question has a 'results' object with more nested objects. You first begin by deserializing the http result using `DeSerializeJSON()` get the `results` object and dump it, analyze the data structure within and finally form your solution.

I will recommend you to start by building up your understanding on the subject.